# Having trouble sorting columns by last row using sort_values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having some issues on how to sort columns based on the last row getting a 'KeyError: -1'

I have tried `df.sort_values(by=[-1], axis=1,na_position='last')` and
  `df.sort_values(by=df[-1], axis=1,na_position='last')`

```
 timestamp AKS  AGI  AA  ATI  ...        TK       TNP      USDP       ZTO
2019-09-10  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  ...  0.063570  0.057432 -0.121778  0.098429
2019-09-11  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  ...  0.083130  0.043919 -0.128889  0.104712
2019-09-12  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  ...  0.080685  0.047297 -0.130667  0.135079
2019-09-13  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  ...  0.090465  0.020270 -0.123556  0.112565
2019-09-16  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN  ...       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
```

some code

```
sorted_df = df.sort_values(by=[-1], axis=1,na_position='last')
```

Expected results to be that the columns are sorted by the last row

Comment: `df.iloc[-1]`, also, you want `sort_index()`, not `sort_values`.

Comment: df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist()[-1])

Comment: After reading up on `sort_index()` I don't think it is going to work for me....Quang Hoang

Comment: I found the solution
`df.sort_values(main_df.last_valid_index(), axis=1, ascending=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to know what you last column is, you can do that by using

```
df.columns.tolist()[-1]
```

So if you want to sort a df by the last column it turns out as

```
df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist()[-1], ascending = False)
```

and then you can na_position

```
na_position : {‘first’, ‘last’}, default ‘last’

first puts NaNs at the beginning, last puts NaNs at the end
```

Comment: I don't think that is what I want to sort by... I want to sort the columns by the last index. So that the column with the largest last index value is first and so on...

Comment: Column with the largest index? I still do not get what you mean. But if you want to sort by the index values of the dataframe itself you can use df.sort_index(inplace =True, axis =1, ascending=False)

Comment: Sorry the column with the largest value at last index

Comment: I have made the edit for sorting using the last column in descending order.df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist()[-1], ascending = False). So in the example posted the largest value of Zto will be first and the corresponding row of it as well.